# Splunk: Count by multiple fields gives wrong result

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I want to write a Splunk query which does the following:

- Group messages by 4 fields: *first_name*, *last_name*, *city*, *country*
- For each group, get the count of messages and the earliest and the latest *birth_date*

What I came up with:

```
<get all messages> | stats count, earliest(birth_date), latest(birth_date) by first_name, last_name, city, country
```

But the count does not work as expected.
When I run this on test data with a single message, the count is 8 though it should be 1.
What's wrong with the query?

Comment: Can you share more about `<get all messages>` and/or post sample data so we can see what is being counted and try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: If there is expected to be a single entry for each tuple then there should be only one birth_date value so no need for earliest/latest.

Comment: While I was trying to create a reproducible example, I found out that this was caused by an error in my search index, i.e. in the `<get all messages>` part. Closing this question.

Comment: why would there be more than one "birth_date" for a given person?

Comment: @warren The actual data has different fields. I agree that my example does not make much sense.